# Getting Html tags value monotouch

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, xamarin.ios

Suppose we have a string variable that its value contains a Html value like

```
<span class =\"Name\">VALUE</span>
```

in monodevelop we can access its value ('VALUE') by this code:

```
Html .FromHtml (Stringvariable).ToString ();
```

Whether the string is a literal string like `"VALUE"`, or an HTML tag like the tag example above, it returns the value. But it had defined in an android library.

***My question is:*** in monotouch how we can do an operation like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  I haven't personally used it in a MT project, but it supposedly can be built from source for use in MT.

Comment: Thanks to your answer. I know this library and believe that it will work on MT but the code that i search was some thing like Html class in monodroid that simply in one line without adding any additional references or libraries to the project gets a simple Html tag values.

Comment: Android has a native HTML class to do this, it does not appear that there is an equivalent in iOS.

Comment: Jason, in ios you can do it via UIWebView's `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`.